# Unity2D: Look at object is flipping my object

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform, quaternions

I am trying to make an object look at the player and it is working as intended but for some reason it is facing the wrong direction. I have drawn an example of what is happening in my game. As you can see for some reason the pivot is facing the wrong direction.

[image]

My code:

```
void Update()
{
    var dir = player.transform.position - transform.position;
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out by deducting -180 to the angle :)